# Flutter async memorizer

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am using my own API. I only want to fetch data once when I log into my account. I found AsyncMemorizer.

```
AsyncMemoizer _memorizer = AsyncMemoizer();
```

I have 3 future functions and they return Future. Normally without AsyncMemorizer it works fine but in this case, I had an error.

```
fetchData(Store store) {
    return this._memorizer.runOnce(() async {
      return await Future.wait([
        fCustomer(store),
        fList(store),
        fCompanies(store)
      ]);
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Store store = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context);
      return FutureBuilder<List<bool>>(
        future: this._fetchData(store),
        builder: (
            context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<bool>> snapshot,
            ) {

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }


          if (snapshot.data.every((result) => result == true)) {
            return screen();
          }
          return Text("Sıqıntı");
        },
      );


    }}
```

error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, dependencies: [StoreProvider<AppState>], state: _HomeScreenState#79c31(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<bool>>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution about it.

```
AsyncMemoizer _memorizer = AsyncMemoizer<List<bool>>();
```

Generic AsyncMemorizer works.